# Can I keep the terminal as the active window, even if it's in the background? - Python 3.3

Tags: python, terminal, xdotool

G'day,

I've just posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823487/using-pyinotify-to-live-refresh-displayed-file). Following on from that, is there a means to lock keyboard user input to the terminal, when it's running behind another window? My system requires a user to scan their barcode (barcode scanner acts as a keyboard. ie. outputs a string of letters and presses enter) inside the terminal. However, the system also requires that a log CSV file be displayed on the attached monitor. As such, with the terminal in the background, the cursor automatically reverts to the log CSV file when opened, which disables the users' barcode scan from being entered into the terminal.

I'm still relatively new to Python, and haven't completely figured out the functionality of this system. I will eventually set it up such that when the system boots, the log file will automatically open on top, with the terminal (and cursor input) running in the background.

Again, I don't have any code to demonstrate my attempts, but I have done extensive research. The only thing I've found that may offer this functionality is xdotool. I could automatically rearrange the windows such that the terminal was always at the back, and somehow automatically allocate the terminal as the 'active' window?

Any help here would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Couldn't you have a small terminal window below the bigger csv log window?   Two windows?  Tiled?  There is no requirement that a terminal be 80x24.

Comment: @lornix: That's a last resort at the moment I'm afraid. I'm sure there's a means of specifying an input entry into a window, regardless of whether it's in the foreground/background, I just haven't found it yet. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You're right, there is, but most window managers raise the active window to the top.  I've got mine (KDE) set for 'focus follows mouse', so if I can put mr mouse over the lower window, it'll get focus, but not be raised (which would happen if I clicked on it).  Usually use this when I need to copy some text place to place.  So yes, it's possible, but you'd need to create a script to move focus and layer the windows as desired.  I'll play with it, much experience with xdotool and its cousins.

Comment: Ah ok, that sounds like quite an involved process. Thanks, I really appreciate it! Also, 'Mr. Mouse' is awesome.